# search full word which is not present in any other sentence

Tags: php, string

I want to search a whole word separately which is not present in any other sub-string.

For ex. I have a placeholder "FIRST_NAME" and REFER_A_FRIEND_FRIEND_FIRST_NAME". I want to replace "FIRST_NAME" with "Data_not_available" and second one with "Data available" But in this case as "REFER_A_FRIEND_FRIEND_FIRST_NAME" contain "FIRST_NAME" then it will replace second also. meaning it is showing"REFER_A_FRIEND_FRIEND_data_not_available".

Is there any way to search only the full word without containing the word ?

Comment: can you please make it clear what you want to search?

Comment: yes sure. Can any string function will search only specific word. not the word which has the search word which I want to be.

Comment: can you share an example as well.

Comment: I have an array in which I have above two placeholders. But I only want to replace FIRST_NAME with other word from that array. But the other placeholder i.e "REFER_A_FRIEND_FIRST_NAME"  has "FIRST_NAME" word, then it is replacing my second holder also "REFER_A_FRIEND_data_not_availble"

Comment: You didnt understand what i am trying to say, i mean update your post with input string and expected output, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

check this code, you can use php `preg_replace()` which match the word if match then replace it .

preg_replace — Perform a regular expression search and replace

this is demo code which match `search` text and replace `update_text`

```
 <?php
$your_string = 'search and search_replace text';
$text = preg_replace('/\bsearch\b/u', 'update_text', $your_string);
echo 'Main Text: '.$your_string;
echo "<br>";
echo 'Update Text: '.$text;
```

then out is

```
Main Text: search and search_replace text
Update Text: update_text and search_replace text
```

for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Why should the OP "check this code"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: yes i will tell it , first answer it then tell details